# Postfix, i want to accept all mail and relay it to my script

Tags: postfix

How to configure postfix as open relay (i want to accept all mail) but use my script foo as tranport and not really relay.

Answer (score 1):

Transport maps can be regular expression based, and also support wildcards, so you can use a *.  From the documentation on [transport maps](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html)

> ```
>    * transport:nexthop
>          The  special pattern * represents any address (i.e.
>          it functions  as  the  wild-card  pattern,  and  is
>          unique to Postfix transport tables).
> ```

With that combined with your own mail delivery service, defined in [master.cf](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html), you can call your script for the emails.  That being said, you don't have to mess with the transport maps, you can simply change the [default_transport](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_transport) to be your newly defined mail handler in [master.cf](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at the [transport table](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) which defines what transport to use for what domains.

Comment: I looked here before, but i am unable to get it working for all domains..

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an alias like so:

```
@domain.com: "|/path/to/my/script"
```

This is what Mailman does.

Comment: Yes but i want it to work for all domains non only for domain.com